# How to capture dynamic result set from a stored procedure using cfprocresult

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, coldfusion

I have a stored procedure that may return 2 or 3 result set depending on the data being processed. How would i use cfprocresult to capture the 2nd or 3rd result set depending on their respective returns?

Comment: Are you saying that the number of result sets returned from the same stored procedure will change?  Some times it will be 2 and other times it will be 3. Will you know ahead of time (based on the call) if the stored procedure will be returning 2 or 3 result sets?

Comment: The stored procedure is the same but there is no way I can know whether it will return 2 or 3 result set while i call the stored proc. depending on the data calculation within the stored procedure the results sets are formed.

Comment: So what happens if you call the stored procedure with the maximum possible number of `cfprocresults` in your call (in this case 3)?  Does it throw an error or is the missing result set variable simply empty?

Comment: It is throwing error when there is no 3rd resultset

Comment: Can you (or have someone else) modify the stored procedure to always return the maximum number of result sets (3) even if one of them will be empty occasionally?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I am musing on. But just wanted to make sure there is some solution in cfproc.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution since you need to know how many result sets will be returned before making the call. Only other option I can think of is to `cfcatch` the error, check if the error is because of missing result set, then make another `cfstoredproc` call minus one result set. Not pretty.

Comment: @Yoosaf - AFAIK, there is no way to determine the number of results dynamically. It could be done at a lower level, but I do not think CF exposes that functionality. Sounds like it would be simpler/cleaner to try what Miguel-F suggested, return the same number of result sets every time, even if the result is empty/null.

Comment: I guess another question is what happens if you call the stored procedure with only one `cfprocresult` and not specifying the resultset attribute? Are all of the resultsets returned? Make that call and dump the variable to see what is there. Maybe you can use this method and then somehow loop over to get all of the data.

Comment: I am modifying the stored proc to always return 3 result sets with 3rd being a dummy in case only 2 result sets are eligible, which I will discard at CF level and do my stuff. Thank you guys for the brainstorm.

Comment: *not specifying the resultset attribute* @Miguel-F - Good thought, but I believe CF will simply default to "1" and end up assigning the *first* result, rather the next one available.

Answer (score 3):

*From the discussion we had in comments*

In this case the stored procedure is returning a varying number of resultsets depending on the data being processed. One call may result in 2 resultsets being returned but another call may result in 3. If the `cfstoredproc` tag is used with the maximum number of `cfprocresult` tags and one (or more) of the resultsets is not returned then an error is thrown.

I don't believe that the `cfprocresult` tag allows for a variable number of resultsets to be returned from the `cfstoredproc` call. It is assumed that you know the number of resultsets to be returned before making the call.

Probably the best approach (i.e. easiest) in this situation is to modify the stored procedure to always return the maximum number of resultsets even if they are empty/null. Then you can check for and handle an empty response in your code.